# Contiguous Memory Allocation (CMA) reserved size vs. System Memory

Tags: multithreading, memory-management, kernel, ram, dma

We are developing a multimedia intensive application running on a freescale imx6q with 1GB of ram. The system is equipped with a 14Mpixel camera. For processing data from this camera we are using a LOT of raw buffers that are HUGE (29MB each).

In fact, I believe at least we are using:
3*29MB (v4l2's ringbuffer) + 1*29MB (v4l2's dummybuffer) + 1*29MB (local copy of buffer) + 50MB used by PCIe DMA

In many cases we got out of contiguous memory space, and the system fail to allocate all the buffers it needs.

At kernel, CONFIG_CMA_SIZE_MBYTES=256 and CONFIG_CMA_AREAS=7.

I am investigating the possibility of rising the CMA size to 384MB, but afraid this may compromise system performance, because the running application is heavily multithreaded. This says (1GB - 384MB) is the remaining space for application and system to run on.

Question is, rising CMA to 384 will hurt system performance?

What is the optimal size of the reserved CMA memory that suits our application, keeping in mind the system is having 1GB ram?

Comment: I'm in a similar situation. Did you get any interesting results by tweaking CMA_SIZE?

Comment: Yes, CMA size increazed. Our application became able to allocate such big buffers without going out of contiguous spaces.